# Authorization cookies not persisted over JsonServiceClient requests

Tags: cookies, servicestack, silverlight-5.0

I just upgraded the ServiceStack assemblies in our Silverlight app from 4.0.9 to 4.0.20.

It seems that the cookies are not persisted with the new version. The JsonServiceClient is created as follows:

```
return new JsonServiceClient(this._address.ToString()) { StoreCookies = true, ShareCookiesWithBrowser = false };
```

(it does not matter if I specify ShareCookiesWithBrowser or not)

When I check with Fiddler the response to my initial POST request to /auth is as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store,must-revalidate,no-cache,max-age=0
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Set-Cookie: ss-id=5cwF1pftMI0R2LphJMjr;path=/
Set-Cookie: ss-pid=KnLVQCQtQe9pvBilJBXU;path=/;expires=Sun, 14 May 2034 13:34:03 GMT
Set-Cookie: X-UAId=;path=/;expires=Sun, 14 May 2034 13:34:03 GMT
X-Served-By: XY Server/2014.1.0 (rev 0) RC1 - XYServer
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/4,020 Win32NT/.NET
Date: Wed, 14 May 2014 13:34:03 GMT
```

But the next request I make looks like this:

```
GET http://localhost:8082/api/server/info HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, */*
Accept-Language: nl-NL
Referer: http://localhost:4637/ClientBin/ServerManagerLite.xap
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.3; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host: localhost:8082
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Am I missing an essential line of code here?

**UPDATE:** This is fixed in version 4.0.21

Thanks,
Robert van Drunen

Comment: Did you create a new instance of `JsonServiceClient` to make the second request (i.e. after authenticating)? `StoreCookies` allows the instance to accept cookies, but it won't persist them across to new instances. So you will loose the authentication cookie. You need to share the `JsonServiceClient` instance in your app.

Comment: No, I only use one instance that is shared. The same code is working with 4.0.9 assemblies. I tried upgrading to 4.0.12 assemblies a few weeks ago but that got me a NotImplementedException on setting the requests user agent in the ServiceStack internals. Because I was busy at the time I postponed updating. That exception is gone in 4.0.20 but now the cookies are not persisted (at least not for Silverlight)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: This is fixed in version 4.0.21